# Cannot start XSP 4.5 using mono on Centos

Tags: asp.net, mono, centos, mod-mono, xsp

**I copied the xsp4 from 4.0 to 4.5 and run the following script:**

```
exec /opt/mono/bin/mono $MONO_OPTIONS "/opt/mono/lib/mono/4.5/xsp4.exe" "$@"
```

**Gives me the error:**

```
[mono] /usr/local/src/xsp-2.10.2 @ xsp4
Could not load signature of Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server:RealMain due to: Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies.

Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
```

**MONO Info:**

```
@ which mono
/opt/mono/bin/mono

@ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.6
# note I've compiled this with --with-libgdiplus=/opt/mono
```

Anyone know what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check,that you set LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to /opt/mono/lib

Check, that Mono.WebServer2 assembly in the gac

```
gacutil -l Mono.WebServer2
```

if it's not, place it here with below command (you have to change directory to xsp source  `xsp/src/Mono.WebServer/4.0`)

```
gacutil -i -package 4.5 Mono.WebServer2.dll
```

If this does not help, you can run xsp4 with strace command to see which and where it tries to find a file

```
strace -e trace=open xsp4.exe
```